# Call a web service outside firewall from EAR installed on websphere via Interface Perimeter

Tags: web-services, proxy, websphere

We have WebSphere 7 installed on server abc which is within my organization's firewall. We are deploying a new WAR file on this WebSphere which will call a web service (let's call it xyz) that's outside firewall and the solution offered is proxy server which forwards any requests sent to it to the Internet using perimeter interface.
[image: This is how the transaction must flow]

How do I configure this in Websphere 7?
So far, I tried adding Generic JVM arguments using -Dhttp.proxy.host and port but the WAR file still calls xyz webservice directly without hopping on the proxy server.
I also tried using apache http server by calling the http server from WAR file and the HTTP server was forwarding the request to Proxy server but it dint work as expected.

PS: We can't open firewall for xyz as xyz is on cloud and has dynamic IPs and transaction end points. While my organization whitelists Web service only on the basis of IP.

Appreciate any of suggestions/ideas you can think of. Thanks.

Comment: You can try iptables or equivalent tools to forward specific requests to proxy server...

Comment: @sozkul Can we also achieve that by updating /etc/hosts file on my server? The server where Websphere is installed, is AIX.

Comment: No, when you set webservice dns name in host file as proxy server ip, it means proxy server is end point for web service . It does not work like proxy.  So you need forward traffic of web service to proxy server with ipsec or iptables or etc. tools. Sorry, i don't have any aix server to simulate scenario. i suggest read about traffic forwarding.

Comment: The JVM properties are `http.proxyHost` and `http.proxyPort`. Is that a typo?

Comment: Yes, @XSurgent that's a typo in my question. I tried the with the right JVM properties. But it gave `Certificate chaining error`. Now I'm on Verisign and the destination server (xyz) is using GeoTrust CA. So we added GeoTrust Intermediate Certs in the truststore and keystore but still received same error. Do I need to have signed certificate on my websphere also? Thanks.

Comment: @Keyur : 1) For the chaining error, you need the root certificate on the WebSphere truststore (the GeoTrust CA certificate, in this case). 2) With the right JVM parameters, does the request pass through the proxy correctly?

Comment: Hi @XSurgent , the Certificate Chaining Error is resolved. We are now getting response thru proxy tunneling in websphere. We are using HTTP tunnel. The only concern now is security. Can you please tell how secure this approach is? Am sending (encrypted) sensitive information through this channel and am worried if HTTP tunneling is safe. Also - (1) Will this call be TLS 1.0? We are on websphere 7. (2) Is https tunneling more secured than http tunneling?

Comment: @Keyur : Glad to hear that the issue has been resolved. As your target web service has an SSL certificate, you are already using HTTPS instead of HTTP. The default SSL configuration on WAS 7 uses TLS 1.0 as standard, but can drop to SSLv2 or SSLv3. For more info on SSL, see [here](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/20803/112299). :-)

Comment: Thanks, @XSurgent . Is there a way to have it TLS 1.2 instead of TLS 1.0 on WAS 7? Is there any fixpack for that? Or can we use another HTTP server (like apache http) to use TLS 1.2? I'm trying to find the directive and module to use apache as TLS v1.2 is a mandate for this interface. Thanks.

Comment: @Keyur: Yes, TLSv1.2 is supported from WAS 7.0.0.23. As you're concerned with security, you should go further to 7.0.0.37 for protection against the POODLE attack. P.S: This discussion is now going tangential to the original question, so consider posting any concerns as a new question. :-)

Comment: @XSurgent Thanks a lot. Your help is much appreciated.